# Storing only bold text from a richTextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently in the process of working on a text editor. I want to save only bold words throughout a richTextBox as a string for better search results, but I have no idea how I would accomplish this. If anyone has any ideas please throw them my way. Thanks!

Comment: please share your code here. without knowing what exactly you are doing it is difficult to provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, you could get the bold text from the richtextbox by filtering the text from th rtf string.

We note that the bold text will have the following text in the rtf text.

```
\b Nice\b0
```

Therefore, we can use the regex to get the bold text

```
"\\\\b(.*?)\\\\b0"
```

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string s = richTextBox1.Rtf;
            var match = Regex.Match(s, "\\\\b(.*?)\\\\b0");
            string t = string.Empty;
            while (match.Success)
            {
                t = t + match.Groups[1].Value;
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
            textBox1.Text = t;
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
```

Result:

[image]